# Calculate a product of an RDD[Array[(String, Int)]] and a RDD[(String, Double)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an `RDD[Array[(String, Int)]]` :

```
Array(Array((yellow,1), (green,1), (orange,1), (red,1)), Array((banana,1), (orange,1), (green,1), (apple,2), (kiwi,1), (pear,1), (red,1)), Array((salad,1), (potato,1), (carrot,1), (green,1), (leek,1)))
```

and an `RDD[(String, Double)]` :

```
Array((pear,1.0986122886681098), (orange,0.0), (kiwi,1.0986122886681098), (apple,0.0), (yellow,1.0986122886681098), (banana,1.0986122886681098), (green,0.0), (carrot,1.0986122886681098), (leek,1.0986122886681098), (salad,1.0986122886681098), (red,0.0), (potato,1.0986122886681098))
```

And I want to have `RDD[Array[(String, Double)]]` that is mapped from the elements first RDD by multiplying values for each word by the values for the same word in the second RDD.

The result should be like this :

```
Array(Array((yellow,1.0986122886681098), (green,0), (orange,0), ...), Array((banana,1), ... , Array((salad,1.0986122886681098), ...))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to make an actual parallel computing on the elements of the first-class array, not on the array itself, I think it is better to `parallelize` the elements (Arrays of words and values) and keep them as a driver collection. Instead of RDD of Arrays, you'll have Array of RDDs. It will come in handy later.

```
val setOneRaw = 
    Array( 
        Array( 
            ( "kiwi", 1 ), 
            ( "green", 1 ), 
            ( "orange", 1 ), 
            ( "red", 1 ) 
        ), 
        Array( 
            ( "banana", 1 ), 
            ( "orange", 1 ), 
            ( "green", 1 )
        ), 
        Array( 
            ( "kiwi", 1 ), 
            ( "pear", 1 ), 
            ( "carrot", 1 )
        )
    )

val setOneRDDs = 
    setOneRaw
    .map( sc.parallelize( _ ) )
```

If you do that, the second RDD will have the same type as others in your primary collection.

```
val setTwo =
    sc.parallelize(
        Array(
            ( "pear", 1.0986122886681098 ), 
            ( "orange", 0.0 ), 
            ( "kiwi", 1.0986122886681098 ), 
            ( "apple", 0.0 ) 
        )
    )
```

By having both of the elements that needs to be processed as RDDs you can `join` them and then multiply the results of tuple produced by join.

```
val mixedSet = 
    setOneRDDs
    .map( _.leftOuterJoin( setTwo ) )
    .map( 
        _.map( 
            ( row ) => ( row._1, row._2._1 * row._2._2.getOrElse( 1.0 ) ) 
        ) 
    )
```

By using `leftOuterJoin` you will address the situation when the first collection has the value for given word but the second doesn't.

Results for data given in the example

```
(orange,1)
(green,1)
(red,1)
(kiwi,1)
(banana,1)
(orange,1)
(green,1)
(carrot,1)
(pear,1)
(kiwi,1)
-=-
(green,1.0)
(orange,0.0)
(red,1.0)
(kiwi,1.0986122886681098)
(green,1.0)
(banana,1.0)
(orange,0.0)
(kiwi,1.0986122886681098)
(carrot,1.0)
(pear,1.0986122886681098)
```

Values for words like "red" or "banana" presisted as they should.

Comment: When I try to parallelize inside of a map I always get an error saying Spark doesn't support nested RDDs.

Comment: Yes. You can't make RDD of RDDs. That's why I used a normal array for storing the RDDs.

Comment: Okay, but when you do val setOneRDDs = 
    setOneRaw
    .map( sc.parallelize( _ ) ) aren't you trying to make a nested RDD? This gives an error when I try a collect.

Comment: Nested RDD is when RDD contains RDDs. In my example I made a **normal scala Array** and filled it with RDDs. Collecting it `setOneRDDs.map( _.collect() ).foreach( _.foreach( println ) )` worked. Look closely to the type of `setOneRaw` - it's `Array[Array[(String, Int)]]`, not an `RDD[Array[(String, Int)]]`. You probably pasted my code over yours without changing the data.